# How to make a swipe up bottom sheet on android using google material design

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I would like to improve my application from a graphic point of view, it is an application for doing physical exercises at home, I currently have an activity with a list of exercises to do, I would like that selected the exercise you can see the details by swiping up, how can I do?

Comment: You can use a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`
It should be what you are looking for

Comment: Or a `BottomSheetDialog` with `BottomSheetBehavior`